C# Library for 2D shape drawing user interface
I am currently developing a Windows Forms Application in C#. In my application the user needs to be able to draw shapes like lines, rectangles and polygons on a specific area and then they need to also be able to edit the shapes by resizing them and moving points around. So whenever they click on a shape, I need to display the handles that allow them to resize or move it and so on.
What I am currently doing is creating custom user controls for each shape from scratch and then placing them on a custom control which inherits from the panel class. Then I am tracking all mouse down and up events, attaching the controls to the mouse pointer or resizing them as needed.
The problem is that coding all of that takes a long time and I was wondering if there are some libraries that already have all that drawing user interface built in so we can implement it and not have to code everything from scratch.
I have been searching for it in the web but most of what I found are libraries like SkiaSharp for redering and drawing shapes. What I am looking for goes beyond that, I want the capability for the user to create and edit the shapes.
Can anyone suggest libraries that have that capability, or maybe point me to specific terms that I should search to be able to find it more efficiently? Open source and free libraries are preferred but any information would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

"What I am looking for goes beyond that" .... Like, what if the user has no mouse? I "solved" the "handles" problem by letting users select an element and (for example) use a "Slider" or a "RepeaterButton" to change a dimension (size) of an element. Accessability.

NShape: Nshape
But it's more for displaying diagrams. But you can still create figures and the user still can edit the objects. So you can try customizing it
What I can advise is to switch to WPF. it is better to use DirectX instead of GDI. I tried once just to write a layered drawing editor on GDI, it's hell.Both 2D and 3D graphics are readily available in WPF
